# Multiple actions as variable?

Tags: vb.net

Welcome ,
how can i put multiple actions as variable ?

like

```
checkbox1.enabled = false
checkbox2.enabled = false
checkbox3.enabled = false
```

i will write like this in many objects code

is there a way to put all of them in variable ?

EDIT:

i can use subs too , more easier .

Comment: copy paste is simplest method.

Comment: the code will be long , i have more than 12 checkboxes , & i want to put them in 3 different locations of the code , no shorter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you use the same nomenclanture that you have used in your question:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim chk() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("CheckBox" & i.ToString(), False)
        If chk(0) IsNot Nothing Then
            DirectCast(chk(0), CheckBox).Checked = Not DirectCast(chk(0), CheckBox).Checked
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Of course this is just an example that will toggle the checkboxes.

**EDIT**:

```
''' <summary>
''' Returns true if all of the checkboxes are checked, false if at least one of them is unchecked.
''' </summary>
Function AllChecked() As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim chk() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("checkbox" & i.ToString(), False)
        If chk(0) IsNot Nothing Then
            If Not DirectCast(chk(0), CheckBox).Checked Then
                Return False 'Not all of the checkboxes are checked
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return True 'All of the found checkboxes were checked.
End Function
```

Good luck.

Comment: Great! , but what if i want to use if on it? , like : if non of the boxes checked (code) exit

Comment: Also, it is a good idea to make sure the found control is in fact a CheckBox. You can do this with another If statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public bool EnableChecks
    {
        set
        {
            checkbox1.Enabled = checkbox2.Enabled = checkbox3.Enabled = value;
        }
    }
```

Then you just set EnableChecks to true or false.  Is this what you're asking for?

EDIT: I personally wouldn't do this because I don't feel getters and setters should be used for this.  Would creating a method to enable/disable them work instead?

```
    public bool EnableChecks(bool enabled)
    {
        checkbox1.Enabled = checkbox2.Enabled = checkbox3.Enabled = enabled;
    }
```

Comment: Chained assignments are not allowed in vb.net

Comment: Just realized I was in the vb section.  I could have sworn I was in c#.  Oops!

Comment: @user1937198 The code may be valid, but the result is different. In VB.NET, it will be parsed as `CheckBox1.Enabled = (CheckBox2.Enabled = (CheckBox3.Enabled = enabled))`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton the code in the question has the same meaning in both

Comment: @user1937198 No, it doesn't. In the C# version, the Enabled property of CB1, CB2 and CB3 are given the value of `enabled`. In the VB.NET version, the value of `CB1.Enabled` is given the value of `(CB2.Enabled = (CB3.Enabled = enabled)`. The results are different - I have checked it in both languages. Your first comment is correct.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I was talking about the OPs code, not yours in my second comment

Comment: @user1937198 Ah, I apologise; I thought your comment was regarding Eric Freeman's answer, as that's what it appears under in what I'm seeing.